# Swift 2 - `indexOf` 2D Array

Tags: xcode, multidimensional-array, swift2, indexof

How can I find the index of an object in a 2D array in swift? the code below gives me the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type
>   '@noescape ([String]) throws -> Bool'

```
let arrayToMatch = ["matched", "YES"]

var arrayOfArrays = [["aaa","bbb"], ["aaa","bbb"],["matched", "YES"],["matched","eee"],["ccc","ddd"]]

let findIndex = arrayOfArrays.indexOf(arrayToMatch) // 2 ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `indexOf` method has parameter which is a closure. It can look like this

```
let findIndex = arrayOfArrays.indexOf {
    (stringArray) -> Bool in
    return arrayToMatch == stringArray
}
```

but it can be shorted to simple one-liner

```
let findIndex = arrayOfArrays.indexOf { $0 == arrayToMatch }
```

Also keep in mind, that return value is an optional (returns nil when not found) and returns only first index of collection's element that matches.